# On page reload props in null when using react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have a main component called `Body` that looks like this

```
class Body extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  _redirect = data => {
    this.setState(
      {
        user: data
      },
      () => this.props.history.push("/user_details")
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/users"
          render={() => <UserList onRedirect={this._redirect} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/user_details"
          render={() => <UserDetails user={this.state.user} />}
        /> 
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Body);
```

Basically there is a page that is loaded when a user visits `/users` which has a list of users, in that page there is a button, onclick of that button the `_redirect` is called which is passed as a callback as shown above.

In the redirect function the data is saved to state and passed to the `UserDetails` component and the url changes to `/user_details` and everything works perfectly the first time.

Now, after that when i try reloading the `/user_details` page, the page for some reason does not receive the `user props`. Why does the props not get passed to this component on page refresh??

Comment: that's normal if you refreach the page `this.state` will became equal to `{}`

Comment: @evgenifotia agreed, state would be null on reload but this isn't state, I'm passing the state of the `body` component as props for the `UserDetails` component, my question is why is props in the `UserDetails` null on page reload.

Comment: because the new state witch will be `{}` is what will be passed. you may check it  in `UserDetails` it will return `undefined` because there is no `user` inside the state

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in a nomamal flow you can pass data from within Routes to other Routes, but on refresh the enitre component is remounted and hence the state is reinitialised to empty. For such cases, you can save the values in localStorage and refill the state in contructor

```
class Body extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
      super();
      const data = localStorage.getItem('data');
      this.state = {
         data: data ? JSON.parse(data) : null
      };
    }

  _redirect = data => {
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.setState(
      {
        user: data
      },
      () => this.props.history.push("/user_details")
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/users"
          render={() => <UserList onRedirect={this._redirect} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/user_details"
          render={() => <UserDetails user={this.state.user} />}
        /> 
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Body);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your app is growing further like an enterprise application **Redux** is a very good option to handle all the state related issues where localstorage does not provide those features.
Please find the link below
https://redux.js.org/.
With Redux and React you can easily handle the state changes by using mapStatetoProps an mapDispatchToProps methods.
One of the good example for containers with react,redux
https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/the-react-plus-redux-container-pattern